# Assign Excel cell value from Datepicker widget Selection using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run the python code I should be able to open my Excel and when I click on one Excel cell I should have my datepicker widget popped up and I should be able to select any date from my datepicker widget as my Excel cell value

**Tried below code but in vain: (Used jupyter Notebook)**

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from openpyxl import *

wb = load_workbook('My_Excel.xlsx')
worksheet = wb.active
worksheet['B1'] = 'Datepicker'
worksheet['B2'] = widgets.DatePicker()
wb.save('My_Excel.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

**Error Occured:**
ValueError: Cannot convert DatePicker(value=None) to Excel

Comment: Please consider adding a code snippet to understand your problem better

Comment: Added my code snippet

Answer (score 1):

```
import openpyxl

n = 0
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\excel.xlsx')
sheets = wb.sheetnames
ws = wb[sheets[n]]
```

try doing this and using n you can access different sheets

Comment: Updated my question. Please help me with the answer